# How to become super user through SSH

Tags: linux, perl, unix

I am using ssh for connecting one of the systems.

I have a perl script in that system which I have to run from my machine. But the commands in remote system runs only when it is in Super user mode (I give su - to become the super user, if I am working directly on the remote system)

But if I have to run the perl script from my system ( I am using `OpenSSH` for this purpose), in super user mode, how should I do it?

By the way, I have placed the command `$sh->system("su -")` . But it asks for the password but does not proceed further. I have waited for 5 mins atleast, even then I didnt get any response after I entered the password.

Can anyone say how to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want ssh to ask for the password, you can add your client user key in the server .ssh/authorized_keys file of the target user. Using this, ssh won't ask for a password anymore.

Answer (score 8):

You could use sudo, and allow your user to become root with no password

Answer (score 4):

Read the entry titled "*Can't change working directory*" on [Net::OpenSSH FAQ](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH#FAQ) to know why it doesn't work.

Then read the other entry, "*Running remote commands with sudo*", to see how you can solve it.